# How can I download a website as string with Angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular, cors, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to download(get) a webpage which returns string, not XML and not JSON.

Basically is there any way to download a webpage as string in Angular4 like WebClient.DownloadString in C#?

**Note:**
I thought I can use http methods(observables, promises, JSONP) to download a website at first. But anyway I tried.

I am not able to use JSONP as I understand because of it is parsing the result as json and I'm getting error because the response is string not JSON.

And observables and promises fail because I get CORS error. And I'm not sure why I'm getting CORS error because it is not a RESTful service, WCF or web api, etc..

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have also tried HttpClient but I got CORS error again.

So I believe there should be some other method or component or module in Angular to download a webpage as string.

Comment: So why angular tag is here? It is about browser CORS. If any site has different domain it can't be accessed by a reuest if it doesn't have CORS headers.

Comment: Because I'm trying to find a way to download a website with Angular. This is not a RESTful service or WCF or API, it is just a webpage. So I'm not sure why I'm getting CORS error as well. So with using http services I can not download a website. But I believe there should be something in Angular I can use but couldn't find. On the other hand, I can download a website with C# or any other language and not getting CORS error. So the question is; is there anything like a WebClient method in Angular to download a webpage as string.

Comment: Are you making a GET request? Does it `Simple request` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Thanks for this but the link you sent is related with RESTful calls. I'm literally trying to find a way to download a website so I think http get requests(observables, promises and JSONP) is not the correct way to download a webpage because they are simply RESTful service methods. So I think there should be other way (a method, component, technology, something else) to download a website in Angular.

Comment: A raw [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: REST is just methodology under HTTP protocol, any page is request, event index.html, browser control all your HTTP requests. So you simply need to do CORS request not CORS.

Comment: XMLHttpRequest gives the same access error as well. I have tried with several websites like example.com, wikipedia, google etc...

Comment: As I sad request to sites that don't allow CORS requests from your domain will be blocked by a browser. There is no way to send not "simple" requests without CORS.

Comment: So you're trying to say that there is no way to download a website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a CORS proxy to get content of sites that don’t send `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` Here’s a simple example:

```js
const proxyurl = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
const requesturl = "https://google.com";
fetch(proxyurl + requesturl)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => document.querySelector("pre").textContent = text)
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

What’s happening there is this:

If a site doesn’t itself send a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header, then browsers will block your frontend JavaScript code from being able to access the response from that site when you make a request to it using the Fetch API or XHR or Ajax methods from JavaScript libraries.

But using the URL `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://google.com` causes the request get made through https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com, an open CORS proxy which forwards the request to `https://google.com` and then receives the response back from it. The `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` backend adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to the response and passes that back to your requesting frontend code.

The browser will then allow your frontend code to access the response, because that response with the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header is what the browser sees.

You can also easily set up your own CORS proxy using https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/

For details about what browsers do when you send cross-origin requests from frontend JavaScript code using XHR or the Fetch API or AJAX methods from JavaScript libraries—and details about what response headers must be received in order for browsers to allow frontend code to access the responses—see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) prevents your website to download a website from a different domain. The Same Origin Policy applies to every web request. Whether it is a website or a REST API makes not difference.

There are multiple ways around the Same Origin Policy:

- The destination webserver may cooperate by setting the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)-header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. (CORS known the concept of "simple request" as mentioned in the comments, but this is not related. A "simple request" is a request which does not trigger a pre-request. But skipping the pre-request does not allows you access to the response, you still need the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header).
- You can convert your website into an Installable Application or Browser Extension
- You can provide a server side script on your domain that proxies the request to the target domain. Please be very careful with this option as it may be easily abused by third parties unless you take extra steps (e. g. white-listing destinations, rate limiting and logging).